Tier 2 static scan CASA for laravel project
I need to verify laravel application that uses restricted api from gmail,
I need to provide CASA scanning test, I read that the tier 2 for static scanning is open source and I can do it by my self,but now I am struggling how can I use it and where are the resources to use it.
